Python uses pydirectinput how to stop at any time?
I used CV2 for template matching, get two coordinates, use pydirectinput to control one of the coordinates to move towards the other coordinates, the speed of its movement is not fixed, so it is impossible to calculate the time that needs to simulate the key, and currently need to take a real-time screenshot to judge the distance between the coordinates in real time to pause the button.
def role_move_down(seconds):
  pydirectinput.keyDown('down')
  time.sleep(seconds)
  pydirectinput.keyUp('down')

result = cv2.matchTemplate(screenimg, small_image, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

At present, I use a loop screenshot to judge, if the conditions are not met, press the key for 0.2s, but this effect is not very ideal, because it is always necessary to repeatedly call keyDown keyUp, I want to make as few calls as possible.

Calculate the distance between the current coordinate and the target coordinate in real-tim and adjust the duration.
import cv2
import time
import pydirectinput
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab

def capture_screen():
    screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab())
    return cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

def get_coordinates(template, threshold=0.8):
    screen = capture_screen()
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(screen, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
    if max_val >= threshold:
        return max_loc
    else:
        return None

def role_move_down(target_coords, threshold=10):
    pydirectinput.keyDown('down')
    while True:
        current_coords = get_coordinates(small_image)
        if current_coords:
            distance = np.linalg.norm(np.array(target_coords) - np.array(current_coords))
            if distance < threshold:
                break
        time.sleep(0.05)
    pydirectinput.keyUp('down')


small_image = cv2.imread('template_image_path', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
target_coords = (x_target, y_target)
role_move_down(target_coords)

